# element css follows jquery declaration, not stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have this initially in my .css stylesheet:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 901px){
    #main_panel {
          width: 750px;
        }
    }

@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 900px), handheld {
    #main_panel {
          width: 500px;
        }
    }
```

And then after some user interaction, this jQuery command changes this CSS-value:

```
$("#collapse").click(function() {
      if ((($(window).width()) >= 600) && ($(window).width() <= 900)) {
           $("#main_panel").animate({width: "500px"}, 'slow');
      }
});
```

When I resize the window to more than 901px, it still follows the recent declaration by the jQuery and not the CSS-declaration in the stylesheet for 901px.

How to prioritize CSS-declaration when resizing the window?
Or how do you handle this better?

Please don't make me rely to $(window).resize() event forever :) That disregards the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

** **EDIT** **

If you want to give priority to the CSS and still be able to animate it, what you probably need is this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/2Fe22/1/**

1) create a "normal" panel class and style it

```
.panel {width:750px;height:400px}
```

2) create a collapsed class and style it

```
.collapsed {width:500px}
```

3) create a function to read the collapsed and normal widths from the css:

```
function getClassWidth(aClass) {
    return parseInt($("<div />").addClass(aClass).css('width'));
}
```

4) handle the click by first animating and then (at the end of the animation) add or remove the "collapsed" class to the panel and removing inline styles left by the animation:

```
var collapsed=false;

$("#collapse").click(function() {
    collapsed=!collapsed;
    if(collapsed) {
        $("#main_panel").animate({width: (getClassWidth('collapsed'))+"px"}, 'slow',afterAnimation);
    } else {
        $("#main_panel").animate({width: (getClassWidth('panel'))+"px"}, 'slow',afterAnimation);
    }
});

function afterAnimation() {
    if(collapsed) $("#main_panel").addClass( "collapsed" ).removeAttr("style");
    else $("#main_panel").removeClass( "collapsed" ).removeAttr("style");
}
```

You do this, so if the user resizes the window and the css changes your screen updates correctly.

** **OLD POST (for reference)** **

If you set sizes with JQuery you may go on setting them this way:

```
var collapsed=false;

$( window ).resize(calculateNewSizes); // When resized
calculateNewSizes(); // At startup

function calculateNewSizes() {
    if(collapsed) {
        // if screen width < xxx set elemt width to yyy, etc.. collapsed version

    } else {
        // if screen width < xxx set elemt width to yyy, etc..
    }
}

// This toggles the collapsed state if user clicks on an element
$("#collapse").click(function() {
      collapsed=!collapsed;
      calculateNewSizes(); // or do the animation here
});
```

This script should be called as fast as possible after the **beginning** of all the elements to be resized to avoid a [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

```
<div class="to be resized">
  <script>
    //do the $( window ).resize(...) here
  </script>
... all other stuff </div>.
```

Warning, this code is **UNTESTED**. It is just to show an idea.

Comment: Hi Francesco, thank you for your suggestion but as I have mentioned, I would like to avoid using the $(window).resize() event from jquery and I would like to just prioritize the css declaration in the external stylesheet. I would not like the original stylesheet to be disregarded and user starts interacting in the website.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery Animate, the element style will directly receive width value.

Like this:

```
<el id="mainpanel" style="width: 500px">
```

This will always override any css on the element unless you use !IMPORTANT:

```
width: 100px !IMPORTANT;
```

http://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/suEHn (DEMO)

Notice that you should avoid that since you won't be able to change this if you need.

Comment: But I cannot put !IMPORTANT to all css since it would be unchangeable forever.